# Typescript 3.0.1 can't understand nested reduce(s)

Tags: typescript, types, reduce

So I have this code that finds all possible combinations of x sub-arrays:

```
const optionGroups: string[][] = [['Beer', 'Not beer'], ['1', '2', '11']];

const combinations = optionGroups.reduce((opt1, opt2) => {
  return opt1.reduce((acc, option1) => {
    return acc.concat(opt2.map(option2 => {
      return (<string[]>[]).concat(option1, option2);
    }));
  }, []);
});

return combinations; // <-- This is not a string[]
```

However Typescript thinks the return type is a `string[]`, when in fact it is a `string[][]`.

The output is `[['1', 'Beer'], ['2', 'Beer']...]` etc

I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix the type. You can try out the snippet for yourself and see.

Even casting it gives the error:

> Type 'string[]' cannot be converted to type 'string[][]'.   Type
>   'string' is not comparable to type 'string[]'.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the type definition of [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) that is being used in this case (the first call to it):

```
reduce(callbackfn: (prev: T, curr: T) => T): T;
```

`T` is the array element type. Since your call operates on a `string[][]` or `Array<string[]>`, `T` is a `string[]`. So the return value of that reduce call has to be a `string[]` as well. So just judging from the types here, everything appears to be correct.

But that it obviously not what is happening when you run the code. The return value is an actual `string[][]`. When you debug your code, then you will see that the types will actually change at run-time.

The reason for this is how `reduce` works when not passing an initial value:

> If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used.

So the first value for `opt1` will be the first element of the `optionGroups` a `string[]`. Then, after the inner code ran, the result is actually a `string[][]`. You can easily confirm this by making the types explicit inside:

```
const combinations = optionGroups.reduce((opt1, opt2) => {
  const result = opt1.reduce((acc, option1) => {
    return acc.concat(opt2.map(option2 => {
      return (<string[]>[]).concat(option1, option2);
    }));
  }, <string[][]>[]);
  return <any>result;
});
```

So the problem now is that `result` is a `string[][]` but the outer reduce still assumes a `string[]` for the previous value (because of its static type). So you will have to use a different type definition for `reduce` that allows a different type for the previous value and the current value:

```
reduce<U>(callbackfn: (prev: U, curr: T) => U, initialValue: U): U;
```

Unfortunately, the initial value is mandatory here, so you will have to pass that. You cannot pass `null` or even an empty array here as that would break your logic, so you will have to adjust your logic a bit to handle the first iteration differently. For example like this:

```
const combinations = optionGroups.reduce<string[][]>((opt1, opt2) => {
  if (opt1 === null) {
    return opt2.map(option2 => [option2]);
  }

  return opt1.reduce((acc, option1) => {
    return acc.concat(opt2.map(option2 => {
      return (<string[]>[]).concat(option1, option2);
    }));
  }, <string[][]>[]);
}, null);
```

Comment: Excellent answer, however that seems to break the logic and give the following runtime error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of null`

Comment: This is obviously because we're trying to do `.reduce` on the newly initialized accumulator, which will then be null. I'm trying to restructure the query.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I was hoping that passing `null` or `undefined` would trigger the “take first element as initial value” behavior but it seems that the `reduce` implementation actually looks at the `arguments` array instead for this. I guess I forget to test that in the end. You will have to change your logic then (or force types) :/

Comment: It's fine mate. I ended up forcing types. Not sure what I should do about this question then. Might not be answerable.

Comment: I did edit my answer to provide a way that actually works and also compiles with proper types. So maybe that’s a viable solution for this problem.

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing something similar. I'll give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the outer reduce to just destructure `optionGroups` into its two elements is strange and is the source of the problem, because when you do a reduce without an initial state, the state is assumed to have the same type as an element of the input, i.e., `string[]`.  The outer callback actually returns `string[][]`, but the mismatch isn't caught because the type of initial state `[]` of the inner reduce is widened to `any[]` without giving an implicit-any error; see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/531).  Enabling `strictNullChecks` will disable this bad form of widening and give you the expected type error.

Comment: Ultimately I think you might be right: It's written in a gimmicky way. I'll try to restructure it.